# Polite alternative to "I don't give a damn about etc."?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, american-english, politeness

I need a ***strong* statement** of rejection of a concept, thing or practice, that means

> X doesn't give a good goddamn about etc., *or* X doesn't give a flying f___ about etc.

but with no vulgar words so I can include it in a semi-formal letter.

What else can go after "doesn't give a"?

Comment: Well you could use ***hoot*** but I'd probably rewrite to use "doesn't [really] care about ... at all"   Or "is not concerned with"

Comment: X's appalling lack of concern for....

Comment: X *could not care less* about Y.

Comment: @Jim - would "flying hoot" work?

Comment: Well it could but it comes off as comical rather than serious.  I suppose it's all in who is saying it.

Comment: @Jim - I'm describing my 14-year-old's reaction to an irrational, arbitrary behavior point system being used at the camp he is attending, to give the director a heads-up that if a counselor tries to draw a line in the sand with him, he may say something inadvertently subversive.

Comment: Then I'd probably go with @BrianDonovan's "couldn't care less" suggestion.   As kids we always said,  "don't give a crap"  but that's not appropriate in this context either.

Comment: There's [_fig_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+fig), but it's not exactly semi-formal, and it has a [vulgar connotation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fig&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: @Jim - could you please write an answer?  I'd like to see how "flying hoot" fares in the voting, and perhaps accept it.  That's where I'm currently leaning.

Comment: There's also *rip*.

Comment: @JeffSahol - Not familiar with that word in this context.  Care to give a usage example?

Comment: @aparente001 I could, but I don't give a rip :) See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49246/i-dont-give-a-rip-whats-a-rip

Answer (score 4):

***utter indifference*** [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indifference) on indifference:

> 1. lack of interest or concern:  We were shocked by their indifference toward poverty.
> 2. unimportance; little or no concern:  Whether or not to attend the party is a matter of indifference to him.

**utter**, as an adjective is explained in [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/utter):

> You use utter to emphasize that something is great in extent, degree, 
>   or amount.   [emphasis]     This, of course, is utter nonsense.
>
> ...this utter lack of responsibility

Example (made up):

> I am utterly indifferent to your opinion on this or  any subject.
>   Please allow me to get back to work.

Translation:  Shut the f--- up and get the f--- out.

**The OP's example becomes**:

X is **utterly indifferent** to ...... or X's **utter indifference** on the subject of ..... is "indecent" or "astonishes me" or "is incomprehensible" or "flies in the face of reason"....I am sure the reader can supply appropriate words of incredulity.

Answer (score -1):

As this requires usage of a minced oath, just how minced is dependant on the audience of your letter. Even the more tame versions may still be received in the wrong light. I would consider rephrasing the statement all together.